# How do I force a related list form to be rendered as a select menu?

Tags: list-form

This is SP2010. Working with lists, and specifically a related list "New Item" form. Problem is, one of my lists has about 300 items, and SP insists as rendering it as one of those look-ahead text input fields. I want it to render as a select menu, as it would if there were only a few elements. I want it to stay as a select menu to keep it compatible with some other jq bits, don't care about performance at this point.

Anybody know how I can force that field to render as a select menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some misery, I found the solution. Do not use the default NewForm.aspx, etc. Instead, use SharePoint Designer to create a new NewForm.aspx, and manually add the Data Bound DropDownList control to the page. It will remain as a dropdown list (i.e., an HTML select menu).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if custom solutions are a go for you, but I've been happily using the "I Love SharePoint" for the lookup columns which provide a custom Asset-picker (find it freely here http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/44989), still wondering why it hasn't been already considered as default by Microsoft. It even comes with a PowerShell that allows conversion of regular Lookup columns to the new ones, and back!

Comment: I'm going to check that out for other projects, but in this instance, I'm looking to serve up a select menu.